# Unable to propagate error from a reactive method

Tags: java, rx-java

I have the following method where in one of the steps, I am calling the throwACheckedExceptionMethod() method.

That method has a chance to throw a checked exception. Now I do not want to handle it here. I want the method which subscribes to it
to handle it.

How can I do that? Cos right now this does not compile cos I am not handling the error here.
Adding doOnError() or throwing the error at the method level doesn't help either. I seem to be missing something about RX Java here.

Could I get some help with this please? Thank you.

```
private Observable<Void> myMethod(Observable<KafkaConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) throws Exception /*Doesn't make a diff*/ {
    return client.rxGetConnection()
            .flatMapCompletable(connection -> connection.rxSetAutoCommit(false)
                    .toCompletable()
                    .andThen(records.flatMapSingle(record -> throwACheckedExceptionMethod(connection, record)).toCompletable()) // line in question
                    .andThen(connection.rxCommit().toCompletable())
                    .andThen(connection.rxSetAutoCommit(true).toCompletable())
            )
            .toObservable();
}

private Single<UpdateResult> throwACheckedExceptionMethod(SQLConnection connection, KafkaConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
    // some operation which may return a Single. 
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The following is a possible option but I do not want to handle the error here as mentioned.

```
private Observable<Void> processTransaction(Observable<KafkaConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) {

    return client.rxGetConnection()
            .flatMapCompletable(connection -> connection.rxSetAutoCommit(false)
                    .toCompletable()
                    .andThen(records.flatMapSingle(record -> {
                        try {
                            return throwACheckedExceptionMethod(connection, record);
                        } catch (Exception throwables) {
                            throwables.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    })
                            .toCompletable())
                    .andThen(connection.rxCommit().toCompletable())
                    .andThen(connection.rxSetAutoCommit(true).toCompletable())
            )
            .toObservable();
}
```

Comment: Does `throwACheckedExceptionMethod` really return a `String` ? Shouldn't it return a `Single`?

Comment: @Joni It returns a Single<UpdateResult> . Wasn't really emphasising on that cos more looking for a solution for the exception. But ya, will update it here for consistency. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `throwACheckedExceptionMethod` method should not throw an exception, because throwing exceptions breaks the observable chain.

Instead, it should return an observable that *emits* the error, [`Single.error`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#error-java.lang.Throwable-):

```
private Single<UpdateResult> throwACheckedExceptionMethod(SQLConnection connection, KafkaConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
    // some operation which may return a UpdateResult 
    return Single.error(new Exception());
}
```

Now the exception gets propagated to the subscriber's `onError` method.